# Prestashop javascript load function works but other not

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

I have a problem with Javascript since I update my prestashop to 1.6.0.9. Since this update, just the on load functions are working ! The others are not working.

If I want a on click function works I have to put it into an on load function.

How I can fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I want a on click function works I have to put it into an on load function.

**That is correct**, if you need an onClick function you have to put it inside the onload function.

```
$(function(){
    $("#whatever").click(function(){
        /*...*/
    })
})
```